GraphQL Resolver return object
Actually, when I do a request with GraphQL I have a result like this :
{
  "data": {
    "events": [
      {
        "_id": "65f0653eb454c315ad62b416",
        "name": "Event name",
        "category": [
          {
            "_id": "66056f64c74b2fb603ba1f59",
            "name": "Category 1"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

But I have only one category by event, so I would like to transform the result like this, without array for category
{
  "data": {
    "events": [
      {
        "_id": "65f0653eb454c315ad62b416",
        "name": "Event name",
        "category":
          {
            "_id": "66056f64c74b2fb603ba1f59",
            "name": "Category 1"
          }
      }
    ]
  }
}

For now, here is my schema
type Event {
    _id: String!
    name: String!
    category: [Category]!
}

And my resolver
export const Event = {
    category: async (parent, args, context, info) => {
        const dbCategories = await Category.find()
        const category = dbCategories.filter((category) => {
            return parent.category.includes(category.id)
        })
        return category
    }
}

I try to transform the array in object but it doesn't work
return { ...category }

Do you have some ideas to help me ?
Thank a lot

Your resolver returns an array:
export const Event = {
    category: async (parent, args, context, info) => {
        const dbCategories = await Category.find()
        const category = dbCategories.filter((category) => {
            return parent.category.includes(category.id)
        })
        return category
    }
}

Try to replace filter by find
export const Event = {
    category: async (parent, args, context, info) => {
        const dbCategories = await Category.find()
        const category = dbCategories.find((category) => {
            return parent.category.includes(category.id)
        })
        return category
    }
}

